# How to use multiple modal windows in one single page

Tags: javascript, html, css

everyone. I'm posting this because i have no way to solve my problem. I'm trying to use modal in my web, but it only accept one and i want to use many at the same time. I'm not using bootstrap (i don't know if that could be the problem).

Comment: Please add your code as well & explain it. Or Read the Guide about how to ask the question. So you can get your problem solve ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

There should only ever be one modal window, by its very definition it is a blocking UI:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window

Answer (score -1):

Well... Playing some with the js code, i found how to make it possible.
Just add some btnX (where X is a number) and in myBtnX (where X is a number). Add more variables and it works.

Comment: This doesn't even make any sense.  What does btnX have to do with a modal window?